# ASP.Net API how to let API accept an IFromFile and an object at the same API call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have the following API that works properly

```
[HttpPost("testing")]
public string Testing(IFormFile file, string str, int num)
{
  return str + num.ToString();
}
```

What I want to do ideally is to pass "str" and "num" in an object instead of each param on its own

Like this:

```
public class Testdto
{
  public int Num{ get; set; }
  public string Str { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("testing")]
public string Testing(IFormFile file, Testdto dto)
{
 return dto.Str + dto.Num.ToString();
}
```

Of course the above format rends an error, it does not work.

Is there a way to make it work? My real API body is quite large and contains nested objects so I can't just pass them all as params in the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the FromForm Attribute :

```
[HttpPost("testing")]
        public string Testing(IFormFile file, [FromForm]testdto dto)
        {
            return dto.str + dto.num.ToString();
        }
```

And add the parameters to request form

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create class having properties as **IFormFile** and other **fileds**.

And pass it to your controller with ***[FromForm]*** attribute

**Sample Code:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("FileUpload")]
 public ActionResult FileUploaded([FromForm] PostRequest postRequest) 
 {
    return Ok(postRequest.str);
 }
```

---

```
 public class PostRequest 
 {
    public int Num { get; set; }           
    public string Str { get; set; }           
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }    
 }
```